# Hive query with with booleans evaluate to null

Tags: left-join, hive

I want on those cases of a.email where there is no b.email mathc. So that b.email will be null in this case, but I am not sure how to correctly write the hive query for this

`select a.email, b.email from dir1 a left outer join on dir1 b where b.email` is null

The output I would expect is

```
abc@aol.com abc@aol.com
bcd@yahoo.com NULL
```

I only want to keep the cases where there is a NULL on the right hand side

Comment: Could you provide some input/output sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use where b.email IS NULL

```
select a.email, b.email from dir1 a left outer join on dir1 b where b.email is null
```